# How to process GRIB files with php

Tags: php, weather, grib

Does anyone know if there's a php library out there that process GRIB files?  I'd like to show global weather on my website using the GRIB (or GRIB 2) files that are available at Environment Canada.  I use php to develop, which is why I'm looking for this.  Thanks....

Comment: there are a lot of weather apps, perhaps you could find an alternative.

Comment: I currently use php to hit the NOAA database.  I prove latitude and longitude and get an XML response, which I parse.  This is great, but only works for US.  I can also do the same thing at Environment Canada to get Canadian weather.  But the only FREE GLOBAL service that I can find provides the data in the GRIB format (it's from Environment Canada too).

Answer (score 1):

The file format is well defined in [NCEP Office Note 388](http://www.nco.ncep.noaa.gov/pmb/docs/on388/) but creating images that are geo-located can be significantly more difficult.  Regardless, there are a variety of links that are useful at http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/  Look for the grib library (Native C source code) and then you can call that code through a shared object call in PHP.

It may be better to preprocess the images and have them available before the client hits your website as generating images from grib can take a little time.

Information and libaries on GRIB2 can also be found through NCEP.